# Emacs: mediawiki save error

Tags: emacs, mediawiki

I've just started to use mediawiki.el to edit out internal wiki page. I've set it up as described. I connect to the wiki, Edit the file I want. When I want to submit my edits I hit `C-x C-s`, it prompts me for a summary, but after it I get the following error:

```
let*: The server encountered an error: (unknown_action) Unrecognized value for parameter 'action': edit
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Based on http://wikimedia.7.n6.nabble.com/Problem-with-action-edit-td1148687.html: What version of MediaWiki do you have (although that shouldn't matter as long as it's not ancient)? And do you have the API enabled (`$wgEnableAPI` and `$wgEnableWriteAPI` in `LocalSettings.php`) on your wiki?

Comment: Thanks! If you move this to an answer I'll accept it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this thread](http://wikimedia.7.n6.nabble.com/Problem-with-action-edit-td1148687.html), the error most likely means that you either have an ancient version of MediaWiki (not likely), or that you have the API disabled.

To enable editing though the API, you need to set `$wgEnableAPI` and `$wgEnableWriteAPI` to `true` in LocalSettings.php of your wiki.